# Getting Error "Cannot login using Kubernetes: invalid role name "abc-reader-xyz-cluster"; nested exception"

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have cluster "ABC". Now I moved the Application to "XYZ" Cluster. And I changed all configuration file with Clsuter "XYZ". Now when I trying to deploy application then getting below error:

```
o.s.v.c.l.SecretLeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener -  - [RequestedSecret [path='bass/orchestrator/sit', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Cannot login using Kubernetes: invalid role name "bass-reader-prod-nezbleu"; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
org.springframework.vault.authentication.VaultLoginException: Cannot login using Kubernetes: invalid role name "Xyz123"; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.VaultLoginException.create(VaultLoginException.java:64)
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.KubernetesAuthentication.login(KubernetesAuthentication.java:107)
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.LifecycleAwareS
```

Comment: It looks like you did not moved all the RBAC roles, the once missing is called `bass-reader-prod-nezbleu`.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to moved those roles ?

Comment: From the error we can only see the role `bass-reader-prod-nezbleu` is missing from your new cluster. You need to find in which namespace the role is by using `kubectl get roles -A`, once you know the namespace you can export the role as yaml using `kubectl get roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io bass-reader-prod-nezbleu -n <name_space> -o yaml><filename_to_save>`. I'm also pretty sure this will not be all and there will be still resources to be moved. So I would check your application files and node what does it need.

Comment: what you get when you write `vault auth list` and `vault list auth/kubernetes/role`...?